# Hibernate 5 Duplicate Mapping with Composite Key

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm dealing with a non-Spring legacy application, with a matching legacy database that is not easily updateable, so I have to deal with the cards that were dealt me.

I'm moving this non-Spring app from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5 and I was running into some issues so let me say they have a primary-hibernate.cfg.xml with these two classes:

```
<mapping class="com.ekotrope.server.model.user.UserRolePK" /> 
<mapping class="com.ekotrope.server.model.user.UserRole" />
```

The first classes is defined as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class UserRolePK implements Serializable 
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "elt",  insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    // getters/setters/equals/hashcode/toString
}
```

The main class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRolePK userRolePK;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "elt",  insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    
    // getters/setters/equals/hashcode/toString
}
```

I have one DAO class, and all I want it to do is just get all the records, that's it.

```
public List<UserRole> getAll()
{
    Query query = HibernateUtil.getSession().createQuery("FROM UserRole");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

This seems like it should be simple, except that I am constantly getting the error as follows:

```
Exception while initializing hibernate util.. 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: 
com.app.server.model.user.UserRole column: userId (should be mapped with 
insert="false" update="false")
```

I've spent a lot of time on StackOverflow looking at previous questions that were asked years ago, and are more Hibernate 3 or 4 questions, and don't seem relevant.   I've tried numerous things including rebuilding my app, and doing cleans in Eclipse to route out the issue, but nothing seems to be helping.

It's also frustrating because the insert="false" and update="false" in the error message seems to be deprecated properties, and in their place should be 'insertable' and 'updateable'

I will keep looking at various sources and I will update when the answer is found.

UPDATE:
I got this working last night, I don't know how, but I did.  I was able to get it working, and I was able to get data from the table roles.  So, the UserRole and UserRolePK mapped in the cfg.xml file worked.  Now, nothing has changed this morning except I did a rebuild for the project, and now it's not working and I get this error again.   It's maddening since I know I am following the code per the docs.   So, if there is something I can fix, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.   I knew there were two ways to create a composite key, and it was with @Embeddable w/ @EmbeddedId, but I think that was broken.   The new code looks as follows:

```
public class UserRolePK implements Serializable  {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId",  referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "elt",  insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    // getters/setters/hashcode/equals/toString
}
```

Now the actual class which uses the composite key is setup as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
@IdClass(UserRolePK.class)
public class UserRole implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId",  referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "elt",  insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    // getters/setters/hashcode/equals/toString
}
```

Once I used both @Id annotations with the @IdClass, whatever problems I had now went away.   I created a simple DAO Class to get one or all records from this table 'roles' and it worked.  This issue is now resolved.